# Symfony / FOSUserBundle : overriding error

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I'm running Symfony 3.4 and FOSUserBundle (master version).
I added 2 new fields in my custom User entity :

- firstname
- lastname

.. and I'm now trying to edit the profile edit form with those 2 new fields.
I followed this tutorial : [Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html), this is my custom Form :

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\PimCoreBundle\Form\Type;

use FOS\UserBundle\Util\LegacyFormHelper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPassword;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->add('firstname', 'text', array('label' => 'Firstname'));
        $builder->add('lastname', 'text', array('label' => 'Lastname'));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_profile';
    }

}


?>
```

my config :

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MyCompany\PimCoreBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "contact@MyCompany.com"
        sender_name: "MyCompany"
    profile:
        form:
            type: MyCompany\PimCoreBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
```

.. and my services :

```
services:
    app.profile.form.type:
        class: MyCompany\PimCoreBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_profile }
```

I made the changes in the config + services ymal files.
But I get this error :

**Could not load type "app_user_profile": class does not exist.**

Can't understand what's wrong and how tu debug it !

Answer (score 0):

This issue disappeared by itself !

This morning I only made a simple refresh and it works. I suspect a caching system on server (APC and co.) to be the guilty.